# Create dictionary from a duplicated keys list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
arrival=[1,2,2,2,3,4]
duration=[5,1,2,3,1,90]
```

I want to create a dictionary from this so it should be:

```
d={1:5,2:1,3:1,4:90}
```

So for the duplicated key=2 it should choose the minimum value=1

My code is :

```
d = {}
for i in range(0,len(arrival)):
    d[arrival[i]] = duration[i]

for key,val in d.items():
    print(key,val)
```

but this takes the last value for duplicated keys not the minimum value.

Obtained results:

```
d={1:5,2:3,3:1,4:90}
```

Expected results:

```
d={1:5,2:1,3:1,4:90}
```

Comment: Convert it to a dictionary of lists first, then pick the minimum of each.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do this is using `itertools.groupby` to find the minimum values in `duration` for each group in `arrival`, and build a dictionary from the result:

```
from itertools import groupby 

it_arrival = iter(arrival)
mins = [min(v) for _,v in groupby(duration, key=lambda _: next(it_arrival))]
dict(zip(set(arrival), mins))
# {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 90}
```

Comment: Another use of zip and groupby, single-line: `{key: min(values)[1] for key, values in groupby(zip(arrival, duration), key=itemgetter(0))}` (`itemgetter` is from `operator`, "values" is an iterator of tuples, we need only the second value, hence `[1]`).

Comment: Yes, nice one @h4z3

Answer (score 2):

Simply (without additional aggregations/grouppings):

```
arrival = [1,2,2,2,3,4]
duration = [5,1,2,3,1,90]
d = {}

for i, k in enumerate(arrival):
    if k not in d or d[k] > duration[i]:
        d[k] = duration[i]

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

creating a new dictionary, where checking if key from arrival is present or not,
oif present then update the value to minimum of existing value and value for key,
otherwise key not present then add the key-pair in that dict

```
arrival=[1,2,2,2,3,4]
duration=[5,1,2,3,1,90]

res ={}

for i, v in zip(arrival, duration):
    if i in res.keys():
        res[i] = min(res[i], v)
    else:
        res.update({i:v})


print(res)
```

output

```
 {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with the Pandas library using the `groupby` function and aggregating using the `min` condition.

```py
import pandas as pd

arrival=[1,2,2,2,3,4]
duration=[5,1,2,3,1,90]

df = pd.DataFrame({'arrival': arrival, 'duration': duration})

df = df.groupby(['arrival']).aggregate({'duration': 'min'})

data = df.to_dict()['duration']
```

```py
[In]: data
[Out]:
{1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 90}
```